# Mongodb - Find the triggers list on the respective collection

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to find all the triggers list created on the particular mongodb collection. This can be achieved on the Oracle database.

Do we have the same on mongoDB? I am not find any references on the same over the internet.

Comment: MongoDB server doesn't support triggers.

Comment: yes, understand. We are using stitch app to create/maintain triggers. Is there any way to get it? The use case is that I just want to know how many triggers were created on my collection with one single query.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/admin/api/admin-v3/#event-trigger-apis